# Authenticate user without a login screen?

Tags: android, security, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

### TL;DR: How can I let only my users read/write to my Firebase storage without having to implement an entire login screen?

I am using Firebase storage to make a simple app that uploads a user photo to storage and provides the user with a link to the image. The app works fine when I keep my rules public:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

However, **ONLY users who have installed my app** should be allowed to upload images to storage (write permission). No one else should be allowed access to read/write to my bucket.

For this task, I have updated my security rules to the following:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't want to have to add an entire login screen just to authenticate my user. How can I authenticate my user in the background without having to implement a login screen?

---

PS: Using [phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) would be perfect, however, that also requires a text to be sent to the user, and I'm trying to have as little user interaction as possible throughout the authentication process.

Comment: Anything in the mobile app is known to the world. Anything received by the server is sent based on the info the app (and as such, everybody) knows. Therefore, it is impossible to limit clients to only your app. You can implement authentication, but even then, it will be possible to connect with valid credentials, not using your app.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth):

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
>   anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
>   anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
>   up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an
>   anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their
>   sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
>   to work with their protected data in future sessions.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have actually looked into anonymous authentication, however, I had some doubts about it. Cant anyone just log themselves anonymously to access the data on my app's storage? Does anonymous authentication have any security flaws that normal authentication doesn't? Please let me know!

Comment: Yes, anyone can log in anonymously. You can't have both identity verification and no prompting for identity at the same time.  From the perspective of Firebase, every user is just a user id with a secret token that gets passed with every request.

Comment: Is there a way to provide any user write access, but no delete access?

Comment: My primary concern is having people delete my users' data

Answer (score 0):

A hack would be to create one user and in the splash screen of your app or the first screen use the hardcoded credentials to go through the authentication.

**Advantage:**

You achieve what you want

**Disadvantage:**

All of your users are seen by firebase as the same person and this is not a best practice

Comment: Hmm...What would the possible disadvantages be to having everyone under one login?

Comment: How would this prevent anybody (outside the app) from connecting to the darabase? (It wouldn't.)